# How can I store values to db from a select box populated by a table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

Here is my select box or option box. I am populating it with table "designation". But after posting the selected option the value is not available in $_POST.

```
    <select name="reporting_head" class="form-control" >
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
            <?php
           $sql = mysqli_query($db->link_id, "SELECT designation FROM tbl_designation");
                  while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){   
          echo "<option value=" . $row['reporting_head'] . ">" . $row['designation'] . "</option>";
}
?>
        </select>
```

This is my $_POST,

$reporting_head  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link_id,(htmlspecialchars(trim($reporting_head))));

Can i find a solution. Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you should have written it thus:

`...(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['reporting_head']))));`

Comment: Thanks for concern but I have extracted all the fields and kept in extract($_POST).